# Subtract values in an array

Tags: powershell

i have the below data in a variable, how do i subtract the time between all the entries ?, right now there are only 3 entries, there can be 1,2...100 or more, how can i create a single variable which has the value of Time[0]-Time[1]...Time[n] as they $count is dynamic ?

```
PS /Users/> $Count

    Time         : 3/31/2020 9:47:19 PM
    DateFormat   : 31/03/2020
    Username     : ONE\a1awp7hpd


    Time         : 3/31/2020 1:00:43 PM
    DateFormat   : 31/03/2020
    Username     : ONE\a1wp7hpd

    Time         : 3/31/2020 12:25:31 PM
    DateFormat   : 31/03/2020
    Username     : ONE\a1wp7hpd
```

Comment: So, you want the time difference between the first and last entry?

Comment: thanks for your response, the difference should be between all the entries

Comment: if there are 3 entries $count = [DateTime]Time[0] - [DateTime]Time[1] - [DateTime]Time[3]

Comment: So what would that be for the 3 entries in your example data?

Comment: correct, but $count is dynamic, so it may have 3 or 100 entries, just need to subtract all the values and put them in an variable

Comment: Right, but your question doesn't make sense - subtracting one `DateTime` value from another will result in a `TimeSpan` representing the difference - subtracting another `DateTime` from the timespan won't yield anything, because "2 minutes minus 1st of January" _does not make sense_ - so please, tell me what exact result you'd expect from "subtracting" the three dates in your sample data

Comment: basically i want to calculate how much time a user is using an application, and the $Time is when he accesses these, hence the time difference between these would give me the number of hours hes clocked in

Comment: So you want to sum the differences between every entry? That's the same as the time difference between the first and last entry

Comment: I'm sure this would make more sense if you provided an example of what output you expect for the given input shown

Comment: yes thats it!!, correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, summation of the difference between each timestamp is exactly the same as the difference between the first and last timestamp, so let's do that:

- Sort the list by the timestamp (if they aren't already sorted)
- Calculate `[newest] - [oldest]`:

```bsh
$oldest,$newest = @($Count |Select -Expand Time |Sort-Object)[-1,0]

$difference = $newest - $oldest
```